# How to make Eclipse/PyDev know a variable is being linked to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

I've got an object class that is provided a dictionary at `__init__()`, which in turns contains nested dictionaries.  What I want to do is create a shortcut to (in this case) a list that is buried several layers into the dict.

Obviously this will work:

```py
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, foo: dict):
        self.shortcut = foo['a']['b']['c']
```

The problem is that I would like to do this in such a way that Eclipse/PyDev knows that `foo['a']['b']['c']` a list (and therefore so is `self.shortcut`), similar to the way that adding `:dict` tells PyDev that foo is a dictionary.

The closest I've come to a solution is:

```py
self.shortcut = list( foo['a']['b']['c'] )
```

But that makes a copy, and I want to preserve the link to foo.  I could turn around and do the assignment in reverse, by following it up with

```py
foo['a']['b']['c'] = self.shortcut
```

But that... that just offends my programming sensibilities.

Comment: You could try something like `self.shortcut:list = foo['a']['b']['c']`

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for an should have figured out.  Thank you!